# Bower suddenly does not install all components

Tags: angularjs, node.js, bower

So that's it. Weird stuff... Since this morning, when I type for example `bower install angular-sanitize`, I only get these files:

- .bower.json
- angular-sanitize.min.js.map
- bower.json
- package.json
- README.md

If I download the package with `npm install` there's no problem at all:

- angular-sanitize.js
- angular-sanitize.min.js
- angular-sanitize.min.js.map
- bower.json
- index.js
- package.json
- README.md

The same applies to any other package. It's like bower couldn't get the .js files or something. Any idea?

Comment: 'bower install' will read the bower.json file and download and install any packages enumerated in that file. 'npm install' with similarly do that for package.json file. these files should be located in the root directory of your project. they are separate package managers pulling files from their repositories that may or may not be the same.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? My co-worker is seeing this same issue. Nobody else on the team is having a problem.